# couldn't deduce template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost-optional

I am trying to use an API which is similar to the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/optional.hpp>

class Base
{
 int id;
public:
 int get_id()
 {
    return id;
 }
};

class A : public Base
{
};

class B : public Base
{
};

class M
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
     t_A,
     t_B
    };
    Type type;
    boost::optional<A&> a;
    boost::optional<B&> b;
    boost::optional<A&> get_A()
    {
        return a;
    }

    boost::optional<B&> get_B()
    {
        return b;
    }

};
```

I need to get to the base through any derived class. So I created a templated function like this:

```
template<class T>
boost::optional<T&> get(M & m)
{
    switch(m.type)
    {
    case M::t_A :
        return m.get_A();
    case M::t_B :
        return m.get_B();
    default:
        throw;
    };
}

int main()
{
    M m;
    //... initialization of m
    int i = get<>(m)->get_id();
    return 0;
}
```

but my function's template argument cannot be deduced :

```
template_sp_1.cpp:63:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(M&)’
  int i = get<>(m)->get_id();
                 ^
template_sp_1.cpp:63:17: note: candidate is:
template_sp_1.cpp:46:21: note: template<class T> boost::optional<T&> get(M&)
 boost::optional<T&> get(M & m)
                     ^
template_sp_1.cpp:46:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
template_sp_1.cpp:63:17: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
  int i = get<>(m)->get_id();
```

trying any of the following is not possible; apparently due to using `boost::optional` :

```
int i = get<Base>(m)->get_id();
int i = get<A>(m)->get_id();
int i = get<B>(m)->get_id();
```

Do you have a solution for such scenarios? (I can't touch the API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Manu343726 already pointed out, your `get()` function has varying return types. But since `A` and `B` have the common base class `Base`, why don't you use a return type of `Base&`?

There is a [bug in `boost::optional`](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10839) regarding references which was fixed in boost 1.58, so you need at least this version.
I modified your example to show how it could work:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp> 
#include <iostream>


#if BOOST_VERSION < 105800
#error boost version must be at least 1.58
#endif

class Base
{
 int id;
public:
 Base(int id) : id(id) {}
 int get_id()
 {
    return id;
 }
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    A() : Base(100) {}
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    B() : Base(999) {}
};

class M
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
     t_A,
     t_B
    };
    Type type;
    boost::optional<A&> a;
    boost::optional<B&> b;
    boost::optional<A&> get_A()
    {
        return a;
    }

    boost::optional<B&> get_B()
    {
        return b;
    }

};


Base& get(M & m)
{
    switch(m.type)
    {
    case M::t_A :
        return (*(m.get_A()));
    case M::t_B :
        return (*(m.get_B()));
    default:
        throw;
    };
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    M m;
    m.type = M::t_A;
    m.a = a;
    Base& base = get(m);
    std::cout << base.get_id() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This example will output:

```
100
```

This of course only works at runtime if the API does guarantee that `get_A()` or `get_B()` return an optional containing a valid reference.
If this is not guaranteed, you can use something like this:

```
boost::optional<Base&> get(M & m)
{
    boost::optional<Base&> base;
    switch(m.type)
    {
    case M::t_A:
        base = m.get_A();
        break;
    case M::t_B :
        base = m.get_B();
        break;
    default:
        throw;
    };
    return base;
}
```

Comment: just to make sure about this bug: is this the bug that is causing the boost::optional not to respect the inheritance ?

Comment: @rahman the bug prevents you to convert `boost::optional<A&>` to `Base&`. but it does not affect the second example, so you could use that.

Comment: Now I am confused! your second example does compile fine with my version of boost but I don't understand why? what is the difference between *"initializing a local `boost::optional base` and returning it"*, and *"just directly returning `m.get_A()` "* ?both of them are `conversion`s aren't they?

Comment: @rahman I don't really know, see https://ideone.com/kBWP4q only `get_3()` fails to compile, you could ask this as a new question

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is pretty clear: Since T does not depend on any function parameter, and you are not passing that T explicitly, the compiler was unable to deduce a value for T.

Note that those a and b optionals have different types, so your get() function is trying to return multiple different types (Hence your try with a templated optional?)

C++ does not work in that way since the type should be determined at compile time, and your decission depends on a runtime value (the switch thing). Consider returning a variant type like boost::variant.